# Why is solve not printing any output?

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following code in *Mathematica*:

```
Solve[{(1 - a)/c == 1/w^2, C == w*a + B (a + x)^.5 - w*(a + x), 
  1/w^2 == (1 - x)/(w*x), B^2/(2*w) == (x + a)^.5, 
  c + w*x == B (x + a)^.5}, {c, w, a, x}]
```

When I evaluate the cell, it just outputs nothing: `{}`. How can I get a solution for this system?

Comment: When `Solve` returns `{}` instead of returning unevaluated, it means that it has come to the conclusion that no solution exists. Are you sure the equations you are solving have a solution?

Comment: Ahhh I'll have to recheck. Thank you very much for your time! EDIT: It appears changing the C to c, as they were suppose to be the same variable, fixed it.

Comment: Also using C is a bad idea, it a protected symbol in mathematica!

Comment: There are more equations than unknowns. Check the `MaxExtraConditions` option.